# Android geofences - doubts about the concept and limits

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am trying to understand the geofences concept correctly, in my case for an android app, and I have two questions.
Based on the documentation and examples, I see that I can create a zone based on a longitude, a latitude, and a radius, and I can create alerts when entering or exiting that zone.
so far, everything is correct.

My intention is the following:

I want to create a zone and be notified if another user, also with my app installed, enters the zone I have created.

Is this possible with geofences?

I am reading about it, but it is not clear to me if it is possible.

My second question is: the limit of 100 geofences per app, is it for each application package name, or for each installed application?

Comment: `want to create a zone` In your app on your device or in your app running on another user device?

Comment: I want to create the zone on my device and, if another user, with the same app, enters that zone, we will both be notified. Thanks

Comment: The other user does not need your app for that. The other user should send location to your app running on your device then. Or how do you imagine all this?

Comment: uhmm, ok. It seems like geofences its no good for what I want to do

Comment: Of course you need one geofence if you wanna check if someone enters a .. geofence. But you need much more in order to get what you want. You could image much more..

Comment: "My second question is: the limit of 100 geofences per app, is it for each application package name, or for each installed application?" for this search SO, it's been answered somewhere already

Answer (score 0):

"Is this possible with geofences?" yes, just for every user fetch geofences data for somewhere (filessystem, enter by hand, form backend) and set up geofences on this particular piece of android device